# selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0] is null

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

Code:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", final_side)
```

This gives me the error log:

- In Chrome:

  ```
  File "...\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 635, in execute_script 'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "...\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "...\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read pro'scrollIntoView' of null
  ```
- In Firefox:

  ```
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0] is null
  ```

Browser info: chrome=68.0.3440.106

Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737

Platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64

Comment: The exception message tells you what the issue is... `arguments[0] is null`. Whatever you are passing in as `final_side` is `null`. Take some time to debug your code and trace back how `final_side` gets to be `null`. We can't do that for you because you've only included a single line of code. Also, please fix the formatting of your error messages. The mix of regular text, code, and bold is hard to read and follow.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: TypeError: arguments[0] is null
```

...implies that the *WebElement* referred as **arguments[0]** is **null** i.e. doesn't contain any reference.

Your main issue is the *WebElement* you are referring as **final_side** doesn't contain any reference to any element within the webpage.

Without the previous commands and relevant HTML it is tough to guess the exact reason of the error.

### Solution

A possible solution would be to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) as follows:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```